# How to upload a folder to Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-worker-roles

I have a worker role that I use to pull data down from Blob Storage OnStart.  Currently I'm testing this by uploading a test.txt file and then downloading it to a local directory.  This is working fine.

I now would like to upload a folder to blob storage.  This folder contains a batch script as well as several executables that the batch script calls.

What is the recommended way to accomplish this?  I think zipping the folder and uploading the *.zip file would be easy...  but then, once I download it locally for the worker role to handle, how would I unzip it without any third party libraries?

If there are better options, I'm open to any suggestions.  Thanks for the help here - this community has been a huge help for me as I ramp up :)

Comment: Why not just upload the individual files?  Storage is cheap.

Comment: I should have noted that there is also a project folder that contains hundreds of files and other folders.  I'd like to be able to download all contents of the container while retaining folders, filenames, etc.  Is this possible?

Comment: Please define pull data down.  You need these for worker role or you need to download these files to the client?  Or something else?

Comment: I need these files for the worker role.  The easiest thing for me is to use CloudXplorer to drop the project folder into the Container... but I can't quite figure out how to download the folder as a folder from blob storage, for the worker role to use.  It's just downloaded as a bytestream, I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take two approaches: Single-file (e.g. zip) or multi-file (with each file in its own blob). Here's my take on it, then a note about unzipping:

**Single zip file**

This is a very easy way to maintain a grouped set of files, like an apache install, or a set of static resources. Downloading to local storage from a blob is extremely simple. And, a zip file can handle any level of nested directories.

Downside: To update a single file, you'd need to create a new zip; no way to simply upload one modified asset.

**individual blobs**

Separate blobs are great when you need to update individual files quickly without worrying about other files. Also, you can direct-link to these blobs whether public or (with Shared Access Signature) private and enbed links in web pages, etc. Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11015058/272109), as well as @Sandrino's, for examples of this. Oh, and if you're planning on exposing blobs via CDN, they'll need to be in individual blobs.

Downside: No absolute mapping to nested directories. Blob storage is arranged by account\container\blob. While you *can* simulate nested folders, you'd need to do some work to map individual files. To download individual blobs, you'd need to grab the container and call `ListBlobs()` to enumerate through individual blobs names.

**How to unzip**

The Eclipse project provides a vbs script which is trivial to use. From a Visual Studio project (or really any script), I'd consider downloading something like [7zip](http://7-zip.org/), which is free and trivial to install. Then just download the zip from blob storage to local storage (in the proper folder), and pass it to 7zip.

I hope this provides you with enough guidance to make the correct decision. If it were *me* and I was storing a build (like tomcat), I'd keep the entire directory structure in a zip. That gives me assurance that I haven't broken something by modifying just a single file. And... I can keep a running history of tomcat versions easily, with multiple zips (in separate blobs).

Comment: Very cool.  I think I'll try to zip everything up then.  This means that I'll need three files in the container: the build archive, the 7zip executable, and a batch script that tells the worker role to install 7zip, unzip the build, and then run the deployment.  Does that sound about right?  Cheers :)

Comment: Sounds about right. 7zip doesn't necessarily have to go in the same container. Have as many containers as you like. The batch script should be part of your Windows Azure deployment. Since 7zip provides an MSI, that can be executed from a startup script. You'll still need to download 7zip to local storage to install it. Easy to do with a public blob, or download it direct from sourceforge. If in private blob, you'd need a way to get to access keys, or have shared access signature to the blob or the container. For now, I'd start simple and go with public blob to store 7zip msi.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `upload-batch`:

```
az storage blob upload-batch --destination ContainerName --account-name YourAccountName --destination-path DirectoryInBlob --source /path/to/your/data
```

This copies all files found in the source directory to the target directory in the blob storage.

Either a SAS-Token (via `--sas-token`) or account key has to be specified.

Also works smoothly with a service principal.

Comment: A useful option to add if you have a lot of large files is `--max-connections`: Maximum number of parallel connections to use when the blob size exceeds 64MB. (It still doesn't upload multiple files in parallel though.)

Answer (score 7):

login to azure cli using az login

1. To upload file use
   `az storage blob upload additional-params`
2. To upload a folder use
   `az storage blob upload-batch additional-params`

Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-upload-batch) for complete commands

Answer (score 4):

You could use Azure Storage Explorer https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/ to upload a folder. It uses azcopy in the background but nice to have a user interface.

Comment: This is my first choice, since I'm lazy. But I think you can only upload one folder at a time (and its subfolders)

Answer (score 3):

With the release of AZCOPY tool you can do this in one line.
Details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy).

```
Cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy"

.\AzCopy /Source:C:\Users\folderName\ `
/Dest:https://storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/storageContainerName `
/DestKey:yourStorageAccountKey /S
```

Answer (score 1):

use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). After installing you have to log in and then you can select your Blob and upload folders like a normal upload process.

I ran into the same issue, tried to solve the problem with uploading a zipped folder but there is no option to unzip the folder in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

try using Azure CLI with the `storage-preview` extension

for example if you have a directory "draft" and you want upload all the content

```
  az extension add --name storage-preview --yes
  az storage azcopy blob upload -c container-name --account-name storage-account-name -s draft --recursive
```

Comment: Please specify that the folder is uploaded itself, so it creates a new folder in blob, instead of just copying the files in the destination blob.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use storage explorer for this. It worked fine for me.
It uses azcopy , you can copy the command if you want. You can connect your storage account using its connection string.

Answer (score -1):

We can drag and drop the required folders which we need to upload. No need to zip/unzip... This would upload all the files in all folders.